# How to loop AHK by user input?

Tags: autohotkey

Is there a way to loop a certain script using user input with `INPUTBOX`?

The script below runs only once when I click the button for it. Is there any way for the script to popup something where it asks for a number for it to loop? Lets say something pops up and i give in "10". Then the script is executed 10 times.

myscript:

```
sleep 100
InputBox, testvariable, Enter your Input here,,,350, 120
send 100
send {Tab}
sleep 100
send %testvarable%
return
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use another **InputBox** and a **Loop**:

```
InputBox, ite, "Repeat...", "How many times to loop?"
Loop %ite% {
  sleep 100
  InputBox, testvariable, Enter your Input here,,,350, 120
  send 100
  send {Tab}
  sleep 100
  send %testvarable%
}
```